# ROS Packages vs. Linux Packages

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, how do ROS packages differ from Linux packages?  Can I expect to use them to install libraries and other software, in the way I expect RPM and DEB packages to manage software installation in Linux?  I would like to update the wiki pages to make any distinctions clearer to those coming from Ubuntu backgrounds.  Thanks, friends!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9302/ros-packages-vs.-linux-packages/) by [RobotJay](https://answers.ros.org/users/243/robotjay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS packages are not related to standard linux packages such as RPMs and debian packages.

ROS packages are described on the wiki at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages

On Ubuntu you [can install](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu) debian packages of ROS [stacks](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Stacks) which contain ROS [packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

do you think the ROS package model will converge eventually to Linux/Ubuntu package model?

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-06**:
Eventually it will likely converge.  The first step in the direction is to make "installation" work.  REP102 was an attempt in that direction, though we needed to rethink exactly how we're going to get there.